# why cannot find enum in different file in C#?

Tags: c#

I have a C# file A which defined some public enum and public struct. Now I need to define errorCode for them. I defined an enum named SubsystemErrorCode in file B. Both A and B don't have class inside. They are in the same namespace In one struct of file A, I try to use the SubsystemErrorCode enum but it give me error tell me :
Error   1   The type or namespace name 'SubsystemErrorCode' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

If I move that SubsystemErrorCode into the same file. no error. But I really want them to be separated. How can I do this? thanks,

File A:

```
namespace SystemSoftware { 
    public struct StatusMessageBody { 
        public ProcessControlStatus State; 
        public StatVal LVP_OK; 
        public SubsystemErrorCode LVP_ERROR_CODE; 
    } 
}
```

File B:

```
namespace SystemSoftware 
{ 
    //public class ErrorCode 
    //{ 
    public enum SubsystemErrorCode : byte 
    {
        NoError = 0, 
        EPCSS_CPU_ERROR = 1, 
        LVPS_ERROR 
    } 
    //} 
}
```

Comment: maybe it's a typo? can you post some code?

Comment: File A:
namespace SystemSoftware
{
public struct StatusMessageBody
    {
        public ProcessControlStatus State;
        public StatVal LVP_OK;
        public SubsystemErrorCode LVP_ERROR_CODE;
}
}

File B:
namespace SystemSoftware
{
    //public class ErrorCode
    //{
        public enum SubsystemErrorCode : byte
        {
            NoError = 0,
            EPCSS_CPU_ERROR = 1,
            LVPS_ERROR
        }
   //}
}

Comment: @5YrsLaterDBA: edit your question with that information!!!!

Comment: @5YrsLaterDBA add code to question and not coment

Comment: no typo, I copied the enum name to file A.

Comment: @5YrsLaterDBA:edit your question, or do I have to do it for you?

Comment: What's the error message you get?

Comment: I just pasted the struct and enum into two files. Compiles fine? Enum is recognized...

Comment: Are the two files in the same project? (assuming your using Visual studio, if not are the two files compiled into the same dll/exe?)

Comment: Are you using Visual Studio or just a text editor or something?

Comment: @5YrsLaterDBA: you're wasting the time of people who want to help you. What error message do you get?

Comment: @5YrsLaterDBA: note that you could have had the answer about ten minutes earlier if you had answered the questions above. In particular, the one about whether the files were in the same project.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Change your enum file to this

```
namespace SystemSoftware.Enums 
{  
    public enum SubsystemErrorCode : byte  
    { 
        NoError = 0,  
        EPCSS_CPU_ERROR = 1,  
        LVPS_ERROR  
     }    
}
```

and in your File A put this up the top (under `using System;`)

```
using SystemSoftware.Enums;
```

or you could asl try in File A

```
public SystemSoftware.Enums.SubsystemErrorCode LVP_ERROR_CODE;
```

instead of

```
public SubsystemErrorCode LVP_ERROR_CODE;
```

Edit: Forgot to say, I'm assuming that both File A and File B are in the same project?
If not, you will need a reference in Project A, to Project B

Ok Edit Again.
I Created Two Files, like you say, in the same project. It works, here they are.

File1.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace SystemSoftware
{
    public struct StatusMessageBody
    {
        public SubsystemErrorCode LVP_ERROR_CODE;
    }
}
```

File2.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace SystemSoftware
{
    //public class ErrorCode  
    //{  
    public enum SubsystemErrorCode : byte
    {
        NoError = 0,
        EPCSS_CPU_ERROR = 1,
        LVPS_ERROR
    }
    //}  
}
```

Comment: I get the idea of adding the Enums namespace, but why would that make a difference in compilation, since they're both in the same namespace on his original code?

Comment: Well it *should* compile fine without the Enums namespace, this should I dentify why it doesn't and also it's a lot cleaner IMO.

Comment: Well we have an Enums project, so yeah if the demand is there.

Answer (score 4):

The only reason for your problem is if the files, A and B, are not in the same project.

In this case the project that has the File A has to reference the project where File B is defined.

Answer (score 0):

Think you are missing a USING statement or have not added a reference to the library.